# How to add commonly used (non-signature) phrase in emails?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, vba, macros

I have a text line with a hyperlink that I would like to readily use in composing emails. It is not a signature, so it doesn’t fit there.

How can I build a macro that would allow me to add this text line whenever I need to at the touch of a button?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBA macro:

```
Sub InsertText()
    ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.TypeText "My text"
End Sub
```

You can then run this macro using button on a ribbon.

There are also more advanced commercial solutions available on the market. I can recommend [ReliefJet Quick Text](https://www.reliefjet.com/Quicks/Features/QuickText) because I'm one of its developers. This tool can insert the formatted text by either button or using a hotkey.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked about writing a macro, however, if you are looking to just insert a piece of text, you don't need macros, rather you could use Quick Parts. Here is a quick tutorial: http://www.slipstick.com/how-to-outlook/insert-text-quick-parts/.